# Default Guid Formatting

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

Consider the following code.

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var a = guid.ToString();
var b = guid.ToString("N");
```

The value of `a` looks like `7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7`.
The value of `b` looks like `7c9e6679742540de944be07fc1f90ae7`.

Is there a way to tell .NET that I want the second form, with format string `N`, by default?

Default behaviors for `ToString` on other types, such as `DateTime`, are tied to the current culture. Is the default behavior for `Guid` possibly tied to the culture in a similar way? (I'm doubtful.)

For compatibility reasons, I need GUID string representations without dashes to be the norm throughout my codebase, but it's very easy to forget the `N` parameter without any warning.

Comment: I doubt this will work but maybe give it a try.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Guid` is an `IFormattable` type, but the `IFormatProvider` that goes into the "full" overload [`ToString(string, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6tk2z69.aspx) is ignored. Quote: *The `provider` parameter is reserved for future use and does not contribute to the execution of this method. You can pass null in the method call.*

Comment: @Blam `Guid.ToString()` ignores any custom format provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The [documentation on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is clear:

> Returns a string representation of the value of this instance in registry format.

And

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.String`
>   The value of this `Guid`, formatted by using the "D" format specifier as follows:
>   `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

`ToString()` for some other objects consults the locale formatter, but not `Guid` unfortunately.

You could define an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for `Guid` and use that instead:

```
public static class GuidExtensions
{
    public static string ToMyString(this Guid guid)
    {
        return guid.ToString("N");
    }
}

// elsewhere
Guid guid = /* ... */;
Console.WriteLine(guid.ToMyString());
```

But I suppose forgetting to call this would be just as easy as forgetting the `"N"` so this may not be much of an improvement. (If you do go this route anyway, please think of a better name for the extension method than `ToMyString()` :-))

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell .NET that I want the second form, with format string N, by default?

No, that's the default behavior of [`Guid.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The value of this Guid, formatted by using the "D" format specifier as follows: 
>   `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` 
>   where the value of the GUID is represented as a series of lowercase hexadecimal digits in groups of 8, 4, 4, 4, and 12 digits and separated by hyphens. An example of a return value is "382c74c3-721d-4f34-80e5-57657b6cbc27". To convert the hexadecimal digits from a through f to uppercase, call the String.ToUpper method on the returned string.

You *could* add a custom FxCop rule (or customize some other static analysis tool) to *detect* usage of `Guid.ToString()` but you can't *prevent* it.